# Perl Split String that has double quotes and space

Tags: regex, string, perl, parsing

I have a string like this: `"abc" "cd - e"`. I need to split this into the two following strings:

1. `"abc"`
2. `"cd - e"`

I tried several options in Perl but could not meet the one I need. Can someone direct me? Thanks.

Comment: also: http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html

Answer (score 2):

```
my @strings = $input =~ /"[^"]*"/g;
```

- Assumes the input is valid. Basically, you can use regex matches to validate or to extract, but doing both at once is quite hard.
- Assumes the quoted fields cannot contain quotes since you didn't mention an escaping mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You can split on whitespace that's preceded by a `"` and followed by a `"`:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my $s = '"abc" "cd - e"';
my @matches = split /(?<=")\s+(?=")/, $s;
# "abc"
# "cd - e"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input will specifically have two strings as you suggest (and not arbitrary *n* strings), then this should work:

```
$s = '"abc" "cd - e"';

$s =~ /(".*") (".*")/;
$s1 = $1;
$s2 = $2;
```

Or you could make it a little more safe by replacing the `.` with "non-quote", i.e. `[^"]`:

```
$s =~ /("[^"]*") ("[^"]*")/;
$s1 = $1;
$s2 = $2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not-so-small implementation of a split_line function that deal with quotes and escaped spaces. Features:

- Simple and double quotes can be mixed: `{'"tutu truc" blah' "'blah tutu' truc"}` => `{"tutu truc" blah}{'blah tutu' truc}`
- Quotes can be in the middle of words: `{h ij'k l'  m}` => `{h}{ijk l}{m}`
- Spaces can be escaped everywhere: `{\ a b\ c d\    e}` => `{ a}{b c}{d }{e}`
- Quotes and space escaping can be mixed: `{'a b'c\ d}` => `{a bc d}`

```
sub split_line {
  my ($string) = @_;

  my @result = ();
  my @quote = (); # stack of quotes we've seen so far, to handle nested single and double quotes
  my $accumulated = ""; # the token we are building
  my $seen_quotes = 0; # Whether we've seen at least a quote or whether we should pass a chunk of only spaces (to pass separating spaces)

  # eat the string piece by piece, separating a quote, some spaces, or a chunk w/o quotes and spaces. 
  while ($string =~ s/('|"|\s+|[^"'\s]+)(.*)$/$2/) {
      my $token = $1;

  #        print "Seen $token (last quote: ".(scalar @quote>0?$quote[-1]:"none")."; accumulated:$accumulated) -- ";
      if ($token eq "'" || $token eq '"') {
          $seen_quotes = 1;
          if (scalar @quote>0) {
              if ($quote[-1] eq $token) {
                  pop @quote;
              } else {
                  $accumulated .= $token;
              }
          } else {
              push @quote, $token;
          }
      } elsif ($token =~ /\\$/) {
          if (defined(my $next_char = substr($string, 0, 1))) {
             #                print " steal '$next_char' ";
              $token =~ s/.$/$next_char/; 
              $string = substr($string, 1);
          } else {
              die "Error: backslash escape at end of string\n";
          }
          $accumulated .= $token;
      } elsif ($token =~ /^\s*$/) {
          if (scalar @quote>0) {
              $accumulated .= $token;
          }
      } else {
          $accumulated .= $token;
      }
     #        print " (last quote: ".(scalar @quote>0?$quote[-1]:"none")."; accumulated:$accumulated)";

      # Push the string if we're out of quotes, and if the coming chunk is a separating space
      if (scalar @quote == 0  && ($string eq '' || substr($string, 0, 1) eq ' ')) {
          #            print " Push\n";
          # Pass the separating quotes, that are space only and never contained any quote
          if ($accumulated ne '' && $seen_quotes || $accumulated =~ /\S/) {
              push @result, $accumulated;            
          }
          $accumulated = '';
          $seen_quotes = 0;
          #        } else {
          #            print " Pass\n";
      }
  }

  if (scalar @quote > 0) {
      die "Error: unclosed quote at end of string\n";
  }

  return @result;
```

}

Here is an example of use:

```perl
my $testline = "a  'b c   c d  ' 'titi' \"toto\" ' ' \" \" '\"' \"'\" '\"tutu truc\" blah' \"'blah tutu' truc\" e\\ f  g\\   h ij'k l'  m\"n \" 'l ' "
                ."\\\" \\' '\\'' \"'\\''\" BHA\\RO \\ n \"o p\"q\\ r";
print "$testline\n"; 
print join "#", split_line($testline);
print "#\n";
```

This displays the following:

```
a  'b c   c d  ' 'titi' "toto" ' ' " " '"' "'" '"tutu truc" blah' "'blah tutu' truc" e\ f  g\   h ij'k l'  m"n " 'l ' \" \' '\'' "'\''" BHA\RO \ n "o p"q\ r
a#b c   c d  #titi#toto# # #"#'#"tutu truc" blah#'blah tutu' truc#e f#g #h#ijk l#mn #l #"#'#'#'''#BHA\RO# n#o pq r#
```

For the record, I implemented this for my project that is available [here](https://github.com/mquinson/po4a/blob/master/po4a#L858). The code on github may evolve to fix issues in the future.